# SharePoint format groupby over full width (group props headerformatter json)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a SharePoint Online list with a groupby in the status field. Now I want to change the whole background of the groupby so that the status row has a different color.
I have already applied JSON to this, but I don't get the entire background adjusted but only a border around the status field.

This is the current JSON:
https://github.com/aprildunnam/ListFormatting/blob/master/GroupHeaderFormatSimple.json

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to color over the full width. Similar thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303964/lists-group-headers-100-witdh

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to format group headers to color over the full width of the list.

**Similar thread**: [Lists: group headers 100% width](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303964/lists-group-headers-100-width/303977#303977)

---

But, you can add different background color for different status values as given below:

Add below code in `style` property of first `div` in `headerFormatter`:

```
"background-color": "yellow",
```

Like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "hideFooter": false,
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "background-color":"yellow",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.count",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.fieldData.displayValue +'(s)  ' ",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": " ",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Conditional background color**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "hideFooter": false,
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "background-color":"=if(@group.fieldData == 'Cases', 'yellow', if(@group.fieldData == 'Pallets', 'green', 'red'))",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.count",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.fieldData.displayValue +'(s)  ' ",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": " ",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Additional**:

If you want to use the predefined classes, check samples given in below Microsoft documentation where they have applied background color using `class` property:

[Build custom group headers and footers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting#build-custom-group-headers-and-footers)

Answer (score 0):

This List View formatting applies a 'full width' background for me:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "= @group.columnDisplayName +' >  ' + @group.fieldData.displayValue",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "#333",
        "color": "#fff",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "width": "100%",
        "padding": "10px 20px",
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "margin-left": "-30px"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Caveats:

- Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using the 'modern' list view, ie where `?env=WebViewList` is appended to the end of the URL.
- The JSON styling above doesn't seem to support grouping of more than one column, [as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77768005).