# Is it possible in SharePoint Online to set list row colors only on the grouped header rows?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Is it possible in SharePoint Online to set list row colors only on the grouped header rows?

I'm hoping I can format the grouped list like this?

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of column on which you have applied grouping, single line of text or person or group?

Comment: Hi @DLM, does my response given below works for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add background color to grouping in SharePoint list. Use below code for your list **view formatting**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue",
      "style": {
        "padding": "5px 10px",
        "background-color": "#d3d3d3",
        "color": "#00bfff",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "position": "absolute",
        "left": "80px",
        "right": "0px",
        "top": "0px",
        "bottom": "0px"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: You might need to adjust value for **left** styling property so that you can see the expand/collapse option on the left. More information at: [Lists: group headers 100% width](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303964/lists-group-headers-100-width/303977#303977)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Click on *Format View* from top right corner of list. Copy and paste JSON code from below to the editor.

[image]

`background-color` attribute will determine the background color.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": 
  {
    "headerFormatter": 
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue",
        "style": {
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "display": "flex",
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
          "border-radius": "6px",
          "align-items": "center",
          "white-space": "nowrap",
          "overflow": "hidden",
          "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px",
          "background-color": "gray"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are more details from Microsoft official documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting#example-color-coded-group-header